# How to include spaces in a text content?

Tags: javascript

I want to ask how to make my paragraph look exactly the same as how i write my text in a textarea?

I want to make it look like the following:

[image]

But currently it's displayed like this

[image]

I'm using a javascript.

I've tried to do this but apparently it doesn't work

```
  
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event, statusParagraph){
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Insert a line break into the content
    statusParagraph.innerHTML += "<br>";
  }
});
```

Comment: Just add [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the `statusParagraph` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below javascript code to achieve that:

```js
// Get the submit-code button element
var submitCodeButton = document.getElementById("submit-code");

// Get the next element after the submit-code button
var nextElement = submitCodeButton.nextElementSibling;

// Add a click event listener to the submit-code button
submitCodeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Get the textarea element and set its value to the text content of pre code
    document.querySelector("pre code").textContent = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
});

// Add a click event listener to the next element after the submit-code button
nextElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Get the textarea element and set its value to the text content of pre code
    document.querySelector("textarea").value = document.querySelector("pre code").textContent;
});
```

```css
pre { white-space: pre; }

textarea {
  height: 240px !important;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h3>Textarea Output Pre Code</h3>
<hr>
 
<div class="form-group">  
<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
  
<div class="form-group">  
<button type="submit" id="submit-code" class="btn btn-success">Submit Your Code</button>
</div>

  
<p>Front End View</p> 
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

Comment: The code looks ChatGPT generated